# How to use property method as a field in query?

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Distributor(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.name + self.surname

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    links = models.ManyToManyField(
        Link, blank=True, related_name='links_by_user')
    distributors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Distributor, blank=True, related_name='distributors_of_user')
```

Now I want to make a query like this:

```
dist_list=request.user.distributors.all().filter(full_name__icontains='')
```

But this isn't working.

How to make such a query?

Comment: what du you exactly want to do? Are you looking for a ' ' in full_name ?

Comment: @RajeshKaushik, '' is a query, it can be anything

Comment: Your full_name is string concatenation on name and surname. I the substring you are searching can be formed by this concatenation, then you can not query this from DB. You have to store another field in db for this query available.

Comment: @RajeshKaushik, yes, I've understood this from the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django filters run at the database level. So it isn't possible to what you would like.

Keep in mind that you can always fall back to SQL if you'd like. No need to spend a ton of time figuring out how to make the Django ORM do this when it is a trivial SQL query:

```
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM distributor_distributor d
        INNER JOIN user_user_profile up ON up.id = %(user_id)s
        INNER JOIN user_user_distributors_of_user udu ON udu.user_profile_id = %(user_id)s 
            AND udu.distributor_id = d.id
    WHERE d.name || d.surname = %(query)s;
"""

dist_list = Distributor.objects.raw(query, {'user_id': request.user.pk, 'query': 'hello world'})
```

Wrap that in a function, put it in a `utils.py` module or something, [baby you've got a stew going!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sr2PlqXw03Y)

Comment: I am getting `no such column: user_id` :(

Comment: Hmm, I guess I never asked if user <-> distributor is a many to many. That would change this a bit. Can you edit your post to add your `User` and `Distributor` models?

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey bravo

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey, yes, they have, I've added User model

Comment: I updated my answer. It assumes your `UserProfile` model is in an app called `user` and your `Distributor` model is in an app called `distributor`. You'll have to update it according to what your database schema actually is.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible. If you want to do that, you would have to do the filtering in python (with something like a list comprehension), like this:

```
[d for d in request.user.distributors.all() if ''.lower() in d.full_name().lower()]
```

Doing this would almost definitely be slower than querying the database, however, if `request.user.distributors.all()` has very many entries.

However, in this specific case, you could probably split up the string you want to query with into first and last name and query each separately? Maybe something like:

```
request.user.distributors.all().filter(name__icontains=name | surname__icontains=surname)
```